# What is the purpose of the second while loop in KMP when building the partial match table?

Tags: string, algorithm, computer-science, string-matching, knuth-morris-pratt

When building the partial match table for KMP:

```c
void buildBackTable() { 
    int i = 0, j = -1; b[0] = -1; 
    while (i < m) { 
        while (j >= 0 && P[i] != P[j]) j = b[j]; //Why is this a while loop!?
        i++; j++;
        b[i] = j;
    }
}
```

How come that second while loop is not a conditional instead? Such as:

```c
void buildBackTable() { 
    int i = 0, j = -1; b[0] = -1; 
    while (i < m) { 
        if (j >= 0 && P[i] != P[j]) j = b[j]; //Why not?
        i++; j++;
        b[i] = j;
    }
}
```

In most of the examples I've tried, this statement is used to reset j to -1 when there is no match, so when the next iteration comes, we compare the first character of the string (P[j]) with the character at position i (P[i]).

Comment: Where did you find this example using that inner while?

Comment: if it is not a while loop, then it has to be either P[i] == P[j] or P[i] == P[b[j]], which is not always true.

Comment: @Yerken, If you could elaborate a bit with an example of this case you mentioned (a case where P[i] == P[b[j]]) in the answers section I would accept your answer and thanks!

user3137702, I found it in the book Competitive Programming by Halim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify first, in OP's notations `m` stands for length of string `P`. Note that `b` is of length `m+1`. (this is one of the implementations, though by far not the most natural in terms of notations, which probably caused the confusion)

Let's see what is `buildBackTable()` is purposed to result in. Essentially, for produced  array `b`, `b[i]` will store the maximum value `j`, such that `j < i`, and `P[0..j-1] == P[i-j..i-1]`, `b[0]=-1`.

It is not so difficult to understand the following properties:

1. `b[i] <= b[i-1] + 1`
2. if `b[i] = j`, then for any `k < j`, s.t `P[0..k-1] == P[i-k..i-1]`, we know that `b[j] >= k`. At the same time, obviously `b[i] > b[j]` or `b[i] = 0`.

What this means is that we can easily enumerate the `k` values from largest to smallest, by going through `b[i] -> b[b[i]] -> b[b[b[i]]]...` and so on.

This enumeration allows us to jump through the prefixes of `P` and find maximum value `j`, s.t. `P[0..j-1] == P[i-j..i-1]` and `P[i] == P[j]`.

**As for ur question**, when conditional check (without loop fails), just consider the string `aaaac`. Then `b[4] = 3`. But `b[5] = 0`. With only conditional check, you would get that `b[5]=3`.